# Stochastic processes, White noise.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I read that a white noise process does not have independent increments. One justification I found of this, from a tutor, is this:
covariance between (Xn-(Xn-1)) and Xn-1.
= Cov(Xn,Xn-1) - Cov(Xn-1, Xn-1) = 0 - V(X), and thus the covariance is not 0, therefore the increments are not independent.

But by that logic increments are only independent if:

Cov(Xn,Xn-1) = Cov(Xn-1, Xn-1) = V(X),

I checked that this is also the case in poisson process. So is it fair to call it a general requirement of all processes for their increments to be independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Cov(X_n,X_{n-1})$$ $$=Cov ((X_n-X_{n-1})+X_{n-1}, X_{n-1})$$ $$=Cov ((X_n-X_{n-1}), X_{n-1})+Cov (X_{n-1}, X_{n-1})$$ $$=0+Cov (X_{n-1}, X_{n-1}).$$ This is true for any process with independent increments and finite second moment, in particular for the Poisson process.

Comment: This answered my query. Thank you.